# Analyzer don't force to implement a "required" Flutter Foundation mark on Abstract classes

Tags: flutter, dart, abstract, foundation, required

I'm thinking on submit an issue but I want to know your opinion to see if it really is.

The case is this: If I have an abstract class with needed common parameter on constructor, the analyzer force to child's to instrument it. But if I do this with a named param with `required` Flutter Foundation mark, the analyzer does not recognize it and allows compiling without problems

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

abstract class AbstractPrint {
  final String stringTest;

  AbstractPrint({@required this.stringTest});

  void printString();
}

class RealPrint extends AbstractPrint {
  @override
  void printString() {
    print(stringTest);
  }
}


void main() {
  final realPrint = RealPrint();
  realPrint.printString();  
}
```

**Update**

When I separate this example to a clean folder and check with `flutter analyze`, the analyzer output is

> error • The parameter 'stringTest' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, and no non-null default value is provided • lib/main.dart:6:33 • missing_default_value_for_parameter
> 1 issue found. (ran in 1.7s)

The strange thing is VS Code compiles without problem and the analyzer don't show anything... :S

Answer (score 0):

When I separate this example to a clean folder and check with `flutter analyze`, the analyzer output is

```
 error • The parameter 'stringTest' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, and no non-null default
         value is provided • lib/main.dart:6:33 • missing_default_value_for_parameter
1 issue found. (ran in 1.7s)
```

The strange thing is VSCode compiles without problem and the analyzer don't show anything... :S